# Cannot open an ICS file link on Desktop/Laptop?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar, meeting-request, uncalendarnotificationtrigger

For our monthly [meetings](https://github.com/Seagate/cortx/blob/main/doc/meetings/README.rst), we have an ICS file which people should be able to click on and add to their calendars.

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Seagate/cortx/main/doc/meetings/CORTX_Monthly_Meet_an_Architect_Series.ics`

It works for phones and tablets but not for desktops/laptops. How can I fix this link (or add more links) to make it a single click for people to add this to their calendars?

Comment: works for me but opens not as  text/calendar?   -what is the mimetype?

Comment: Do you want to add this ```ICS``` file to [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r)?

Comment: When I try to open the ICS into my calendar app on Windows (One Calendar), it shows the error message: "Recurrences in ICS are not supported". Could be an issue with recurring events?

Edit: but it also allows me to add the calendar invite after that error message, so maybe it works fine. Probably just an issue with certain calendar apps.

Need more clarification on which apps it's not working in.